# private app settings

Tags: facebook

Iam developing a facebook app, where once the user register to my app and while using the app that shouldn't be known to any other user that he is using that app (something like private app). Please suggest. We appreciate your early response.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy to do. Set "Social Discovery" to Disabled on the advanced settings page for your app.  Happy coding!